# spark sql date conversion and performing calculation

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have created a data frame from CSV (as per the below screenshot) and registered as a table (createOrReplaceTempView), later I am trying to performing some calculations on DOB columns fo find the employees whose age is more than 30. And I am trying to run the below query, but getting error. Please correct or advise me. Thanks!

```
spark.sql(date_format(to_date(DOB, 'yyyy-dd-mm'), 'dd-MMM-yy') as new_dob).show()
```

[image]

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: please don't include real person info in your questions

Answer (score 2):

Your `DOB` has multiple date format
Try-

```
spark.sql("select coalesce(to_date(DOB, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), to_date(DOB, 'dd-mm-yyyy')) as new_dob from <view_name>").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As previous answer said, the DOB field is in mixed format, so need to use coalesce().
Here is a solution in Scala.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  ("Adam", "8/14/1933"), ("Bob", "02-02-1948"), ("Cathy", "05-11-1941"), ("Donald", "5/26/1953")
  , ("Edward", "07/26/1981"), ("Flora", "04-15-1992"), ("Gio", "3/8/2001") 
).toDF("name", "DOB")
df.show

val currentDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2021-01-22")   // Use currentDate as basis to calculate the age over 30
val df1 = df.withColumn("new_DOB", coalesce(to_date($"DOB", "MM/dd/yyyy"), to_date($"DOB", "MM-dd-yyyy")))  // convert the multi date format DOB field to date type column
  .withColumn("months_in_between", months_between(lit(currentDate), $"new_DOB"))   // not necessary - just to show the calculated # of months between from the function
  .withColumn("years_in_between", months_between(lit(currentDate), $"new_DOB")/12) // not necessary - just to show the calculated # of years between from the function divide by 12
  .filter(months_between(lit(currentDate), $"new_DOB")/lit(12) > 30.0)    // Only keep the records with age over 30
df1.show
```

Here is the output:

```
+------+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  name|       DOB|   new_DOB|months_in_between| years_in_between|
+------+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  Adam| 8/14/1933|1933-08-14|    1049.25806452|87.43817204333334|
|   Bob|02-02-1948|1948-02-02|     875.64516129|72.97043010750001|
| Cathy|05-11-1941|1941-05-11|     956.35483871|79.69623655916666|
|Donald| 5/26/1953|1953-05-26|     811.87096774|67.65591397833333|
|Edward|07/26/1981|1981-07-26|     473.87096774|39.48924731166667|
+------+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Here is a solution using Spark SQL Temp View:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  ("Adam", "8/14/1933"), ("Bob", "02-02-1948"), ("Cathy", "05-11-1941"), ("Donald", "5/26/1953")
  , ("Edward", "07/26/1981"), ("Flora", "04-15-1992"), ("Gio", "3/8/2001") 
).toDF("name", "DOB")
df.show
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view_0")

val currentDate = "2021-01-22"   // Use currentDate as basis to calculate the age over 30
val df1 = spark.sql("""
select *
from (select name, DOB, coalesce(to_date(DOB, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), to_date(DOB, 'MM-dd-yyyy')) as new_DOB from temp_view_0) s
where months_between('2021-01-22', new_DOB) / 12 > 30
""")
df1.show
```

Here is the output:

```
+------+----------+----------+
|  name|       DOB|   new_DOB|
+------+----------+----------+
|  Adam| 8/14/1933|1933-08-14|
|   Bob|02-02-1948|1948-02-02|
| Cathy|05-11-1941|1941-05-11|
|Donald| 5/26/1953|1953-05-26|
|Edward|07/26/1981|1981-07-26|
+------+----------+----------+
```